# Specifiy files in publish profile to be removed?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, csproj

I have 3 different settings files being used with a .NET Core 2.2 app
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.Test.json

Im using a publish profile that targets a specific build configuration (eg. Test), and in my publish profile, I added this to attempt to remove the appsettings files I DONT want deployed.  No sense in deploying production settings to a dev server...

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>appsettings.json</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>appsettings.Development.json</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, when I publish, since in Visual Studio, all 3 files are present.  How can I specify those other 2 files get removed on publish ?

I also tried putting this in my csproj file, but all 3 files end up being published

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' "/>
    <None Update="appsettings.Development.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' "/>

    <None Update="appsettings.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' "/>
    <None Update="appsettings.Test.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' "/>

  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Build configuration has no bearing on ASP.NET Core apps. Since there's nothing like config transforms and such going on, the same published app code can be put in *any* environment. What ultimately controls which environment-specific configs get load in is the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable, not how you published. That is why publishing includes all the files; there's no mechanism to know in advance which are relevant or not.

Comment: In practice this is hardly a problem. No secret information should be going into these JSON files anyways, so who cares if `appsettings.Production.json` exists on your dev server?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but put this into your .csproj file to check if it helps.It works in vs2017, .net core  on my side.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Test'">
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
    <None Include="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Test.json" />
    <None Include="appsettings.Test.json" />
    <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
    <None Include="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually i am creating different build configuration for different deployments (different machines) so i am naming additional appsettings as build configuration name.
So i end up with this small pattern (in .csproj file)

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="appsettings*.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Remove="appsettings*.json" />

      <None Include="appsettings.json;appsettings.$(Configuration).json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
<Choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this one, but just a thought, have you tried setting those to only copy when it matches the build configuration expected, e.g.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Production' "/>
    <None Update="appsettings.Development.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Development' "/>
    <None Update="appsettings.Test.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Test' "/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Also please check your .net core version is not affected by https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/881